# iOS Background Thread blocking UI when printing to console

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have to retrieve a list of users and user data from Firebase. The data is relatively large so I used a background thread to retrieve it using the following code:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        FIRDatabaseReference *ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
        [[ref child:@"users"] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
            for (FIRDataSnapshot *userSnapshot in [snapshot children]) {
                NSLog(@"key %@ and value %@", userSnapshot.key, userSnapshot.value);
            }
        }];
    });
```

The problem occurs when the block starts executing. As the output is printed to the console, any user interaction with the application is blocked. I have tried replacing **DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND** with **DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT** but didn't get any success.

Comment: NSLog is serialized across all threads so if the main thread tries to NSLog something while a background thread already logging something then it will block the main thread while it waits for the other thread to finish.  Are you sure `observeSingleEventOfType:` doesn't call its block on the main thread?

Comment: While the application is not responding, press "pause" in the debugger and see what the main thread is doing.

Comment: @dan, So the main thread is not logging any information. That I know for sure. How can I verify what thread the observeSingleEventOfType is being called on?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the block and see what thread it's on when it gets stopped or call `[NSThread isMainThread]` to see if it's on the main thread.

Comment: @PhillipMills So I paused the application and I got the method executing on Thread 1, which I assume to be the main thread. How can I make it execute on the background thread since what I'm doing is clearly not working

Comment: I would expect DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT to work.  Can you add the stack trace for that thread to your question so we can see the sequence of calls?

Comment: The Firebase Database will do all network and disk I/O *off* the main thread. But it will then call your block *on* the main thread, so that you can interact with the UI. To make sure your code isn't blocking that thread, you'll want to run the block itself on a different thread again, e.g. by calling `dispatch_async` inside it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That worked for me. Thanks for the help guys.